# IOS : Multiple storyboards (one for the login/signup, one for the main app)

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm discovering storyboards and would like to use them for a new application.

I would like to know if it makes sense to have two separate storyboards, one for the **login/signup** related views and one for the main application views.

The purpose is to keep both storyboards clean and easy to maintain.

What would be the drawbacks of such approach ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest only having separate storyboards if it becomes an issue for you. I have gone down the path of having separate storyboards, and didn't find any advantage organizationally. It wasn't worth keeping track of which view was in which storyboard.

Once you move to a universal app it is probably more useful to have one storyboard for iPhone and one for iPad. I currently have 3 storyboards, and they are not organized according to what type of view, but which environment will be using the views.

- iPhone Storyboard
- iPad Storyboard
- Shared Storyboard(some views you will use between both)

For me, storyboards are nothing more than just a container to dump my views, and prevents a bunch of separate .xib files all over the place(initialization of ViewControllers from the storyboard is much simpler though). I used segues for maybe a week, but then the app's needs quickly outgrew the limited benefit of transitions.

It is actually really easy to copy and paste between storyboards, so don't be afraid to try a bunch of different arrangements to see what you like. You'll just need to adjust which storyboard you instantiate the object from obviously.

Comment: Thanks Kekoa for your answer. I will go with one storyboard for until I really feel the need of separating stuff.